# What is this obscure crash report (stack trace) saying?

Tags: ios, swift, crash-reports, crashlytics

I've received a crash report in `Crashlytics` that seems nonsense to me; only based of a few characters and method name my guess is that it's somehow related to a model inherited from Realm `Object`.

- Could you please give any clue what's going on here?
- why Crashlytics was unable to provide line numbers? *(while there's been no issue with other crash reports)*
  [image]

Comment: Is that you have any reloadItems function?

Comment: it may not be able to give you the exact line number as the error might be occurring inside closure, although I am not sure but I have observed sometimes it doesn't give the line number of the crashes inside closure

Comment: @jaydeep yes it's true. But unfortunately it's a long method. and my main need is to know the exact reason for this crash(since based on the stack trace I can guess which part crash happens.

Answer (score 0):

It's showing you where in your code the crash is occurring. It gets a bit tricky with these crash reports in Swift because you don't get exact line numbers, but you do get the closure number. It looks like the easiest place to start is `BaseDao.swift` at line 41, follow that closure to `FavViewController`'s `reloadItems` function and check what's happening to the `LeafBriefModel` object?

We'd need to see more code to fully be able to help, but that should be a start.

Comment: Thanks. I've had no problem with other crash reports for Swift code, so far(always with the line number). Yes, BaseDao.swift is a good start, but I need to know the final crash reason. Do you have any idea why Crashlytics is reporting in this obscure way?

Comment: It seems to make sense for the most part, but it's hard to know the real reason without seeing the code. That should make it clear.